# CIDR entries and router

Tags: cidr

A router has the following CIDR entries in its forwarding table:
Address/mask    Next hop
135.46.56.0/22  Interface A
135.46.60.0/22  Interface B
135.46.40.0/23  Interface C
default Interface D
Where does the router forward it, if a packet with the following IP adress arrives: 135.46.63.10

Answer (score 0):

it goes to interface B because you point 135.46.60.0/22 to it.

```
Network: 135.46.60.0/22
First IP: 135.46.60.1
Last IP: 135.46.63.254
Broadcast: 135.46.63.255
```

you can see this address is within this range. 
Always remember doh, the most specific route will be taken.